# How to express "causal loop" Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests, science

> Anything that happens,
> happens.
>
> Anything that, in happening,
> causes something else to happen,
> causes something else to happen.
>
> Anything that, in happening,
> causes itself to happen again,
> happens again.
>
> It doesn't necessarily do it in chronological order, though.

― [Douglas Adams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Adams) [in the preface of his Sci Fi novel](https://en.wikiquote.org/w/index.php?title=The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy&oldid=2944489#Preface_2) [Mostly Harmless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mostly_Harmless) (1992)

In Science Fiction works involving time travel,
[causal loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_loop) are a common trope:
Some event indirectly causes or enables itself.

Some examples even occur in the story
presented in the popular [online Esperanto course of lernu.net "La teorio Nakamura"](https://lernu.net/en/kurso/nakamura):

- Said namesake Theory

  > is passed by Heleno (visiting from 2182)
  >  to Filipo Nakamura in 1982,
  >  who will later (somewhen in the early 21st century) publish it in an unimportant scientific journal,
  >  where it's mostly forgotten
  >  because it cannot be well understood yet.
  >  From there,
  >  the theory is rediscovered
  >  at some time after Filipo's death
  >  and

  ... once the advancement
  of the rest of the field of physics
  has caught up enough
  that the theory
  and its once too-novel-to-comprehend concepts
  can be readily understood,
  all physics students have to learn it.
  This includes Heleno,

  > thus enabling her to pass the theory on
  >  to young Filipo
  >  when she travels back to 1982.
- Filipo's older self,
  visiting from 1982 from (probably again) 2012,
  instructs young 1982 Filipo
  to go to the [67th Universala Kongreso](https://uea.org/kongresoj/UK/1982) in Antwerp, Belgium
  and to meet

  > Lunjo

  at the train station there
  and to invite her to a coffee.
  Older Filipo can tell younger Filipo
  that she'll accept the invitation
  and also what she'll wear
  (how young Filipo can recognize her
  despite never having seen her, yet),
  because he himself can remember

  > that very meeting he had
  >  with his then-future wife
  >  when he was 30 years younger.

So I came to wonder:
**How is the concept / term *causal loop* properly expressed in Esperanto?**

The "causal" part seems straight forward:
[kaŭza](https://vortaro.net/#ka%C5%ADza_kd)

> definition from PIV
>
> Rilata al kaŭzo, konsistiganta kaŭzon: *kaŭza interrilato*; *la kuracado devas turni atenton al la kaŭza momento*; *kaŭza verbo* (➞ *faktitivo*).

But what kind of *loop* is a *causal loop*?

- *buklo* ([PIV](https://vortaro.net/#buklo_kd), [ReVo](https://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/bukl.html#bukl.0o); not just locks of hair, but also loopy bands etc. and loops in graphs, so this might fit)
- *lopo* ([PIV](https://vortaro.net/#lopo_kd), [ReVo](https://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/lop.html#lop.0o); a looping when flying, so probably not?)
- *maŝo* ([PIV](https://vortaro.net/#ma%C5%9Do_kd), [ReVo](https://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/masx.html#masx.0o); can be a whole mesh or a single loop, so maybe?)
- *banto* ([PIV](https://vortaro.net/#banto_kd), [ReVo](https://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/dlg/index-1g.html#bant.0o); a bow or knot, so probably not)
- *fermita vojo* ([ReVo](http://www); technically the most fitting, but kinda lame, isn't it?)

(Let's ignore that some fictional timelines, such as in the movie plot of [Predestination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predestination_(film)) or the [Jeremy Bearimy of The Good Place](https://thegoodplace.fandom.com/wiki/Jeremy_Bearimy_Timeline) aren't simple rings but loop back in complex manners forming a knot, which would probably be *nodo* or in more involved cases *plektaĵo* in Esperanto.)

Comment: While there doesn't seem to be an Esperanto Wikipedia article about the subject, [the Wikidata entry](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q2525268) ([currently](https://www.wikidata.org/w/index.php?title=Q2525268&oldid=1339605878)) names it _paradokso de tempobuklo_ and alternatively _buklo de kaŭzeco_, probably mirroring the French terms _boucle de causalité_ and _boucle causale_.

Answer (score 3):

- causal loop = kaŭza ciklo / kaŭzociklo
- causal chain = kaŭza ĉeno / kaŭzoĉeno

*Cyclic* already is *cikla*.

Answer (score 2):

From the field computer science you also have the term [*iteracio*](https://vortaro.net/#iteracio_kd) for a loop for repeating actions.  However I do not think that the term iteration is suitable here, as the idea of iterating is to stepwise refine something.

I would approach this question from another angle. As far as I understand, here we have a happening that kicks off a series of happenings which finally kick off the first happening. In essence a cause causing itself can be described as *memkaŭzo*. Furthermore since all causes in that chain are such *memkaŭzoj*, would the chain not be *memkaŭza serio, serio de memkaŭzoj* or if you prefer the word *ciklo*, a cycle, *memkaŭza ciklo, ciklo de memkaŭzoj*?

Comment: _iteracio_ could be used for each time of performing (i.e., traveling along) the causal loop, though would probably make more sense in a [time loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_loop) where every iteration can and usually will be (be it blatantly or every so slightly) different. (A causal loop in contrast is never-changing and, from its own perspective, eternal. As all its "iterations" are indistinguishable from each other. One could say that there really is only one iteration, which kinda goes against the idea of what an "iteration" (and probably an _iteracio_) is.)

Comment: @das-g, thank you for your feedback. I see iteration as a process of stepwise refinement, which we are not talking about. On a second thought you are right, _ciklo_ is ok. I have rewritten my answer.

Answer (score 1):

feedback loop - retrokupla ciklo;
https://eo.wiktionary.org/wiki/Aldono:Vortaro_angla-Esperanto_f

Answer (score 1):

Dependas de la situacio. Dum parolata priskribo de filmo oni tre verŝajne povus uzi `tempa buklo`. Kvankam nerigora, tiu koncepto estas facile komprenebla kaj iel ampleksas ĉiujn ceterajn aferojn: interrilatojn, kaŭzojn, ktp.

En tia kunteksto, `destina buklo` ankaŭ bonus, kaj ĝi altirus la atenton ĉefe al la travivaĵoj de la partoprenantoj. `Destini` povas [signifi](https://vortaro.net/#destini_kdc): *Antaŭdecidi, kion iu spertos aŭ faros*.

Iom pli science oni povus paroli pri `spacotempa buklo`.

Sub tiuj bukloj troviĝas la koncepto `retrokaŭzo`. (`retro` [signifas](https://vortaro.net/#retro_kdc) *movon aŭ agon faratan kontraŭe al la normala direkto* ) [ĉi okaze, de la direkto de la tempo]. `Retrokaŭzo` povus utili por difino de "causal loop".